# How does the groovy range operator behave wiht other operators? What is the operator precedence?

Tags: groovy

I'm staring at a short line of groovy code, and I can't understand it.

Input:

```
1..<2+1+(3..<4)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How do I start to parse this? `1..<2+1` results in `[1, 2]` which is fine. But then I can't make sense of the later part. For example, where does the 5 come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting example! It's confusing at first but the range operator has low precedence, so that the first range operator is actually being evaluated last.

It's evaluated as:

```
1..< (2 + 1 + (3..<4))
```

which, as the range `3..<4` is just `3`, becomes

```
1..< (2 + 1 + 3)
```

finally giving

```
1..<6
```

which is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as you found.

The expression leads to a runtime error if the second range generates a list instead of a single value.

https://ideone.com/YTNBLm

Groovy's operator precedence is documented here: https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html

Comment: Wow, I would not have guessed that 3 + [3] is legal and gives 6.